# High cpu load in Chrome with Moonlight plugin on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, lubuntu, moonlight

I am using Lubuntu 12.04 64bit, stable Chrome and Moonlight plugin. The problem is when I try to load this page: http://ms01.oe3.fm/oe3metafiles/Player/Player.html - It is online radio player for Silverlight. It is probably poorly written, because when the tab with player is focused, CPU load is around 30%. When I focus another tab, CPU load goes down to 1-2%, which is acceptable and music is still playing of course.

However in Lubuntu, CPU load is 100% when the tab with player is focused, but it doesn't change when I focus different tab.

Is there anything I can do to listen to this radio and have decent CPU load ? It's funny, but this simple problem keeps me tied to Windows and I can't switch to Linux because of it :-(

Thanks for any help and hints in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Mozilla Firefox instead of Google Chrome or Chromium, for some reason Google Chrome and Chromium use 100% of my CPU too, so I switched to Mozilla Firefox and now every find is going great. And Google Chrome and Chromium also "eat" a big part of my RAM memory to run.